# Undefined Index

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm getting an undefined index error in this code:

```
function get_userdata() {
                    global $db;
                    global $user;
                    global $data, $value, $line;
                    $id = $_SESSION['exp_user']['userid'];
            $row = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_staff WHERE id = $id");
        $user = array();
        while ($line = $row->fetch_assoc())
             {$user[ $line['data'] ] = intval($line['value']);}
}
```

Error being:

```
Notice: Undefined index: data in /includes/functions.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: value in /includes/functions.php on line 11
```

Line 11 being `{$user[ $line['data'] ] = intval($line['value']);}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there is a field called "data" in the tbl_staff table?

Comment: There's most likely no data and value columns in tbl_staff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your variable $line['data'] does not return a primitive value, i.e. an int or a string.

Here is how i would build the array.

```
while ($line = $row->fetch_assoc()){    
    $hc[] = $line['data'];
    $hc[] = intval($line['value']);
    $user[] = $hc;
    unset($hc);
}

print_r($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code was reused, but for some reason, the data table hadn't been copied across.